# Overlay a CSS gradient with an RGBA colour?

Tags: css, overlay, background-image

I'm wanting to add a transparent black overlay to a button for it' :active state, so when you click it, it's the same gradient but with just an overlay of e.g. `rgba(0,0,0,.3)`

The way I thought this would work is (using webkit in this example):

```css
background:rgba(0,0,0,.3), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%,#bababa 100%);
```

or without the comma, and the order reversed... but nothing shows up at all!

I'm not keen on adding another div to act as the overlay to do it, so is there a strictly CSS way to do this? I was thinking maybe it's a `:before` or `:after` pseudo class, but I don't have a clue how to use these!

Would really appreciate an answer, this has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `::after` pseudo-element.

First, you need to define the button CSS with `position: relative` and then use `::after` with `position: absolute`, like this:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
}

.button:active::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**Live Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YwPHu/)

Comment: The one problem with this technique (at least, the way you have implemented it) is that if the text is anything but black, it will fade that as well--[see revised demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YwPHu/1/), whereas minitech and I just manipulate the background as the OP originally intended. With some creative `z-index`, the `:after` could still be made to work right.

Comment: @ScottS You are right, the overlay is over the button so anything below the button are going to be dark. This is a respond what alexbass asked.

Comment: Yeah I don't have the problem with text being darkened or anything, and this is exactly what I'm after. Thank you Fong-Wan!

Comment: `::after` is a pseudo-element. That's why you prefix it with two colons in CSS3.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that; `rgba` defines a colour, not an image. What you can do is use a gradient that's not a gradient:

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%,#bababa 100%);
```

This is why I always specify `background-image` instead of using the shorthand when developing - it makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 1):

### Think in Reverse

Set `background-color: black` and overlay the gradient with your colors converted from hex to rgba (initially set to `1` for alpha), then on `:active` fade the gradient to `0.7` (which will show 30% black) alpha.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEhsG/2/).

```
button {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 1) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, 1) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, 1) 100%);
}

button:active {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, .7) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, .7) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252, 252, 252, .7) 0%, rgba(186, 186, 186, .7) 100%);    
}
```